# Pull a certain value from within a series of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pulling data from an XML file, converting it to json and then an array to be able to handle it.

The issue is because of the structure of the XML, it's like inception. Arrays inside of arrays inside of more arrays.

```
Array
(
[0] => ...

[3] => Array
    (
        [records] => Array
            (
                [record] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 506
                        [sequenceNumber] => 1
                        [values] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [picklistOptionId] => -1
                                                [refId] => 230
                                                [value] => **VALUE**
                                            )
...
```

I want to be able to call the "**VALUE**" by the **refId** of 230. What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr[3]['records']['record']['values']['value'][0]['value']
```

There are downsides to having arrays of this many dimensions. e.g., they are less maintainable and (in some cases) slower.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was going to do that, but the series may change. I want to be able to call the value by the refId of 230.

Comment: @LarryBrettWilbourn "the series may change" What is static?

Comment: The RefID will always be the same. But depending on what data is entered, $arr[3]...['value'] may become $arr[6]...['value']

Comment: @LarryBrettWilbourn Will ANY OTHER VALUE of any other key anywhere in any of the dimensions of the array be equal to `230`?